# Why Azure Function parses date as MM/dd/yyyy even if the region has different culture?

Tags: c#, datetime, azure-functions

The Azure Function app is deployed in **Central India** region where the default format is **dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss**. The string to date conversion works as expected in local environment (In India region).

In the live version, the string to date conversion is like "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt". What is the reason for this behaviour?

```cs
string dateString = "25/12/2020 10:55:58";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dateString = date.ToString(); 

// In Local: 25-12-2020 10:55:58  
// In live:  12-25-2020 10:55:58 AM
```

Function app location:
[image]

Comment: Where does the string date come from?  The ToString() method will use the local culture.  Does the string date come from a person entering info or from another app?

Comment: It comes as a http request to the azure function

Comment: I think you need an HTTP header to solve issue to make sure you get corrected date format : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's parsing them the same, but outputting them incorrectly.  Try specifying a format in your ToString() function.

The reason for this is that the default output format (when not explicitly specified) is based on the machine it's running on.  Your live machine is probably set to non-Indian date formats.

Comment: Yes, in `dateString = date.ToString();` the string representation is dependent on the current culture of the current thread. By default it is inherited from the regional settings or _locale_ of the machine it is running on. You can do stuff like `dateString = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`.

Comment: Thanks @jeppe. May I know how to change this setting in my machine and not in the code?

Comment: @Deepak I do not know exactly how it works in Azure. On a Windows machine, for example, under Settings, you can find stuff like Change date and time formats, or Change region and language settings, etc. Then after changing them, restart the app. Then if nothing within the app configures what `CultureInfo` to use in the app, then the setting from Windows is "inherited" and matters for all `.ToString()` that do not pass a format provider.